# CoreML initialization fails: MTLTextureDescriptor has width greater than the maximum allowed size

Tags: ios, coreml, coremltools

I have a Keras CNN model that I converted to CoreML using [coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools). It works perfectly on simulator but not on the iPhone X. It crashes just on initialization:

```
let cnn = MyCnn()
```

…with error:

> MTLTextureDescriptor has width (44100) greater than the maximum allowed size of 16384.

After having read SO posts with similar errors, I thought that maybe this is a GPU issue, so I tried to set

```
usesCPUOnly = true
```

However, I can only send options during prediction time and there seems to be no way to set this before initialization—where the crash occurs.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* set it during initialization by passing in an `MLModelConfiguration` object.

But it's probably a good idea to make your model smaller. It sounds like this is just way too big for a mobile phone.

Comment: Are you trying to use 1-D convolutions? Core ML doesn't *really* have those and re-uses the 2D convolution for this, which is probably why you run into the texture limit. One option could be to split the audio data into several part, feed these through the model separately, and then combine the results at the end. Personally, I'd probably use BNNS to implement this on the CPU, or TensorFlow Lite, and see if that is fast enough.

Comment: Actually my shape is (1,1,44100). Trained with Keras CNN (all 2D convulations), using Tensorflow. I also converted my model to tf-lite. But choosed to convert to coreml since can be used with swift and seems to be easier then c++ api. Any advantages why I should consider tf-lite? I never heard about "split the audio data into several part, feed these through the model separately" Is that a common practise in Keras? I dont think my model can learn to classify this way. tnx

Comment: No, it's not common practice. But it could be used as a workaround for this Core ML error you're getting. (I think you can run TF Lite models using Google's MLKit, which may be easier than using the TF Lite C++ API.)

Comment: Google's MLKit. Never heard before, will check. bedankt!